# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Battery Indicator

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery, indicator

For the past week I have noticed that when I bring my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T420) out of sleep mode I am missing the battery indicator.

I have used the following command to try to alleviate the problem:

`setsid gnome-shell --replace`

All of this with no success.  Instead I get a message "Something went wrong" and proceed to log out - only to log in and begin my session all over again.  About 2/3 of the time I have to `reboot` just to get the battery indicator back.

Is there an easier way to correct this issue that will not involve rebooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more intense Googling I discovered the following command:

`systemctl restart upower`

I replicated the issue again by putting laptop into sleep mode and then executed the command after resuming from sleep and this resolved the issue.